# Damped camera using GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have read about the damping. Basically it is smooth camera movement. However, I am not sure how to implement damping using C++, OpenGL, and GLM.

Help me with a small sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement inertia. This would make your camera slow down smoothly. To do this, you can declare the camera as an object.
You can do this:

```
class Movable
{
        public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float xmovement;
        float ymovement;
        float zmovement;
        float xrot;
        float yrot;
}
Movable camera;
//omitted code that handles camera acceleration itself
camera.x+=camera.xmovement;
camera.y+=camera.ymovement;
camera.z+=camera.zmovement;
camera.xmovement*=0.99f;
camera.ymovement*=0.99f;
camera.zmovement*=0.99f;
glm::mat4 ViewMatrix=glm::perspective(90f, 1.0f, 0.001f, 30.0f)*glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(camera.x, camera.y, camera.z), glm::vec3(camera.x+sin(xrot), camera.y+tan(yrot), camera.z+cos(xrot)), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
//Then pass ViewMatrix into your Vertex Shader.
```

Modify the `0.99` constant to a higher value to make the camera stop more slowly, or lower to stop faster.
*Please note that the camera might never truly stop. But from a certain point it'll move so slowly that it'll be unnoticeable.*

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer friend. Regards :D